# FindView in release mode always uses useCache = true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've read online that when MVC is compiled in release mode the FindView and FindPartialView method of the IViewEngine interface always is called with useCache = true. Is this true? If it is, is it a bug in MVC? If it is not a bug, what's the reasoning behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This is true.  The reasoning is because it makes the application run faster.  If you didn't use the cache then every time you have to find a view that you already found, you would have to scan the file system looking for a match to the view name.

Comment: well, this would be problematic. If I don't find a match using the cache I should try to find it without it. Why would the same method be called twice with the same values? Why would this work any differently than on Debug mode? First call it with true and if nothing was found call it with false.

Comment: This has nothing to do with debug/release mode.

Comment: You can download the source for ASP.NET MVC at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/ to see for yourself.

Comment: An issue related to this is still open http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8201?PendingVoteId=8201

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the constructor of VirtualPathProviderViewEngine (which is a base for RazorViewEngine):

```
   protected VirtualPathProviderViewEngine() 
   {
        if (HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) { 
            ViewLocationCache = DefaultViewLocationCache.Null;
        }
        else {
            ViewLocationCache = new DefaultViewLocationCache(); 
        }
    }
```

One can see that while debugging Razor does indeed use a NullLocationCache, but, if you check ViewEnginesCollection.FindView() and ViewEnginesCollection.FindPartialView() you'll see that the views are searched once with useCache in true and a second time with the useCache in false:

```
        return Find(e => e.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, true),
                    e => e.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, false));
```